# Assigning variables to use in query

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am moving from Oracle to SQL Server and I am noticing differences regarding assigning variables in a query. I wonder if someone could write me a simple example of how I can do this in SSMS please?

In the example below I am looking to assign the variable @date1 at the beginning of the select statement so that I can simply change the date at the top instead of having to change it several times in the query where @date1 is used several times.

```
SELECT *

FROM table

where date = @date1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example the syntax would be as follows:

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME
SET @date1 = '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Then reference @date1 in your query as you have above.

More broadly, the syntax is:

```
DECLARE @<name of variable> <type>
SET @<name of variable> = <value>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date1 DATE = '2018-04-11'
```

This code may be fine, but be aware of dates formats :[date (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql)
and the need of using either Date, Datetime, or Datetime2.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Simple declares
DECLARE @Variable1 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Variable2 DATE
DECLARE @VariableTable TABLE (
    numberColumnName INT,
    textColumnName VARCHAR(MAX))

-- Chained declares
DECLARE
    @Variable3 VARCHAR(100),
    @Variable4 INT

-- Declare with initiation
DECLARE @Variable5 INT = 150
DECLARE @Variable6 DATE = '2018-05-05' -- Implicit conversion (varchar to date)
DECLARE @Variable7 FLOAT = 1945.15 * 1648.12 / @Variable5 -- Expressions can be used
DECLARE @Variable8 INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sys.objects)

-- Chained declares with initiation
DECLARE
    @Variable9 VARCHAR(100) = 'Afla',
    @Variable10 INT = 9164 * @Variable5

-- Change variable values (without declaring)
SET @Variable1 = 'Some value'
SET @Variable2 = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

For your example:

```
DECLARE @DateFilter DATE = '2018-05-16' -- Use ISO standard date format (yyyy-MM-dd) when you hard-code them as literals

SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable AS T
WHERE
    T.DateToFilter >= @DateFilter
```